# I have an error after sign file using usb token and sent it to invoicing portal

Tags: c#, api, usb, token, digital-signature

I make a method to sign json file and it work good but when I sent this file to invoicing SDK portal.it give me an error: (Step-03. ITIDA Signature Invalid Signature • 4041 4041:Couldn't parse digital signature[Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]) and that is the code I used :

```
    private async Task SignFileAsync(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        // Read the input file into a byte array
        byte[] inputBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilePath);
        // Check that the input file exists and is not null or empty
        if (inputBytes == null || inputBytes.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Input file is null or empty.");
        }
        // Create the canonical version of the JSON as per algorithm described
        string canonicalJson = CreateCanonicalJson(inputBytes);
        string canonical = CanonicalJson1(inputBytes);
        // Compute the SHA-256 hash of the canonical JSON
        byte[] hash = ComputeSha256Hash(canonical);
        // Create a new instance of the CmsSigner class with the digital certificate obtained from the USB token
        if (cert == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("USB token not found or PIN code is incorrect.");
        }
        // Create a new instance of the CmsSigner class with the digital certificate obtained from the USB token
        CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert);

    
                    // Create a new instance of the SignedCms class with the hash to be signed and the detached flag set to true
                    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(hash), true);
       // signedCms.SignerInfos[0].SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.UtcNow));
        // Sign the hash with a CADES-BES signature using the CmsSigner object
            signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
        
     

        //(step 5) Encode the signature into a Base64-encoded string
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedCms.Encode());
       
        // Include the Base64 encoded signature in the original document JSON in a new element
        string signedJson = AddSignatureToJSON(canonicalJson, signature);
         
         // Write the signed JSON to the output file
        await System.IO.File.WriteAllTextAsync(outputFilePath, signedJson);
        // return File(signedBytes, "application/octet-stream", "signedfile.bin");
    }
    //(step 2: Create canonical version of the  JSON as per algorithm described)
    private string CreateCanonicalJson(byte[] inputBytes)
    {
      string inputJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputBytes);
        SerialzeJson serialze = new SerialzeJson();
        JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(inputJson);
        JArray add = new JArray();
        foreach (JObject item in jsonArray)
        {
            string r = item.ToString();
            var inputJson1 = r.Split(new[] { ",\r\n      \"signatures\":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string inputJson2 = inputJson1[0] + "}";
            //string ino = inputJson1[1];

            if (inputJson2.StartsWith("{"))
            {
                inputJson2 = inputJson2.Replace("{\r\n  \"documents\": [\r\n    ", ""); //10 space 
            }
            JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(inputJson2);
             add.Add(parsedJson);
            serialze.Serialize(parsedJson);
        }
        string canonicalJson = add.ToString();

       return canonicalJson;
    }


    //======================================================
    private string CanonicalJson1(byte[] inputBytes)
    {
        string inputJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputBytes);
        SerialzeJson serialze = new SerialzeJson();

        string pass="";
        JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(inputJson);
        JArray add = new JArray();
        foreach (JObject item in jsonArray)
        {

            string r = item.ToString();
            var inputJson1 = r.Split(new[] { ",\r\n      \"signatures\":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string inputJson2 = inputJson1[0] + "}";
            //string ino = inputJson1[1];

            if (inputJson2.StartsWith("{"))
            {
                inputJson2 = inputJson2.Replace("{\r\n  \"documents\": [\r\n    ", ""); //10 space 
            }
            JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(inputJson2);
            pass = parsedJson.ToString();
            add.Add(parsedJson);
           
        }
       
        JObject ca = JObject.Parse(pass);

             string canonicalJson1= serialze.Serialize(ca);
        return canonicalJson1;
    }
    //======================================================
    //(step 3:Apply sha256 hash on the byte array created from canonical version byte array (using UTF-8))
    //Helper method to compute the SHA-256 hash of a string
    private byte[] ComputeSha256Hash(string input)
    {
        using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            return sha256.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        }
            }

            //Helper method to add the signature to the original document JSON in a new element
            private string AddSignatureToJSON(string canonicalJson, string signature)
            {
                DeSerialize deSerialize = new DeSerialize();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(canonicalJson))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The JSON string cannot be null or empty.", nameof(canonicalJson));
                }
                JArray Recive = new JArray();

                JArray parsedJSon = JArray.Parse(canonicalJson);
                foreach (JObject item in parsedJSon)
                {
                    string x = item.ToString();
                    JObject parsedJson1 = JObject.Parse(x);
                    JArray signatures = new JArray();
                    JObject signatureObject = new JObject();
                    signatureObject.Add("signatureType", "I");
                    signatureObject.Add("value", signature);
                    signatures.Add(signatureObject);             
                    parsedJson1.Add("signatures", signatures);
                    string t = "{\r\n \"documents\": [" + parsedJson1.ToString() + "]}";
                    JObject parsedJson2 = JObject.Parse(t);
                    Recive.Add(parsedJson2);
                }
                string K = Recive.ToString();
                return Recive.ToString();

            }
```

I am try to sign file using USB token to sent it to invoicing portal

Comment: Kindly include a sample of Source Document JSON and the corresponding Canonical String and Full-Signed Document JSON.